# SQLite greater than comparison return equal values as well.

Tags: python, sqlite, date, datetime

I am using SQLite with python. I have a database with two fields (timestamp, reading).

the timestamp is an ISO8601 string formatted like this "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSSSSS".

When I run this SQL query:

```
SELECT timestamp, value FROM 'readings' WHERE timestamp > datetime('2017-08-30 14:19:28.684314')
```

I get all the appropriate readings where the timestamp is since the date provided but I also get the reading from the datetime I pass in (in the example: '2017-08-30 14:19:28.684314').

My question is why is the greater than comparison operator pretending it's a greater than or equal to operator?

Comment: Hmm, not an _SQLite_ (as a matter of fact any _DB_ system) expert, but there are 2 things on my mind: either the *micro*s was rounded to fit in 6 digits, either there's some conversion that involves date localization (adding/subtracting) a number of hours/minutes.

Comment: I had thought about that but I dismissed it because I assumed that the system would round the same input datetime the same way. This would, in theory, mean that even with rounding it shouldn't return the input value as a valid response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. I will detail it here in case it is helpful to someone else.

It was with my query. SQLite does not have a direct type for date's or datetime's.

My old query:

```
SELECT timestamp, value FROM 'readings' WHERE timestamp > datetime('2017-08-30 14:19:28.684314')
```

was implicitly relying on SQL to figure out that the **timestamp** field was a datetime. SQLite stores them as **TEXT** fields internally.

When I modified my query to the following:

```
SELECT timestamp, value FROM 'readings' WHERE datetime(timestamp) > datetime('2017-08-30 14:19:28.684314')
```

I started to get the results that I was expecting.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite does not have a separate data type for timestamps.

`datetime()` returns just a string in SQLite's default format:

```
> select datetime('2017-08-30 14:19:28.684314');
2017-08-30 14:19:28
```

This does not include milliseconds. So the comparison ends up between a string with milliseconds against a string without milliseconds; the first one is larger because (after the first 19 characters are equal) it has more characters.

Calling `datetime()` on both values removes the milliseconds from both values.
It might be a better idea to call `datetime()` on neither value and to compare them directly.